# MySQL - The 'optimise' function?

Tags: mysql

I have noticed in phpMyAdmin you can click 'optimise' on tables, and it runs:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name
```

What does this actually do?

Should I have some cron job running daily that runs OPTIMIZE TABLE on my tables?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29406&seqNum=3)

> An optimized table structure is
>   different than a well-designed table.
>   Table structure optimization has to do
>   with reclaiming unused space after
>   deletions and basically cleaning up
>   the table after structural
>   modifications have been made. The
>   OPTIMIZE SQL command takes care of
>   this, using the following syntax:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name[,table_name]
```

Think of it like defragging your tables.  A cron job might be a good idea, but do it during low/no load as it locks the tables.

Comment: Defragging tables! That makes it clear. I might do it monthly in a scheduled downtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the [MySQL documentation about that command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html). After reading that, do you still have questions?

Comment: As a beginner programmer, I found it hard to grok the concept of just *reading the documentation* which always seemed too difficult to comprehend, i.e. I wanted the documentation in layman's terms. I think this might occur for a lot of beginner programmers, hence the manual type questions that keep popping up here.

Comment: If you read the docs and still didn't understand, then *say so*. Describe what about the documentation confused you. For example, "I saw that the documentation says 'XYZ,' but I don't understand what that means." In this case, your comment on the accepted answer suggests that "defragmenting tables" was the key to your understanding, showing that you didn't read the documentation at all. The documentation says the command will "defragment the data file." It's OK if you don't understand the docs, but it's *not* OK if you haven't even bothered to try. And you have to try *every* time.